# Correct way to start as sessions when two same apps work on the same domain

Tags: php, session

I have two identical apps working on the same domain, one at root and the other one a folder. Eg.

```
myapp.com
myapp.com/secondapp
```

What is the correct way to start a session in the app so the session data does not get interleaved? Currently I have just

```
  if (!session_id())
    session_start();
```

and when I log into one app, the session gets transferred when I log into the other one.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set a unique session name in at least one location:

```
session_name('globalsession');
session_start();
```

---

```
session_name('subfoldersession');
session_start();
```